# Bluetooth application Fatal Error

Tags: android

thanks for your help in advance. I'm building an application that allows me to send messages from one device to another using the bluetooth. this is the code that I have.

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.bluetooth.BluetoothAdapter;
import android.bluetooth.BluetoothDevice;
import android.bluetooth.BluetoothServerSocket;
import android.bluetooth.BluetoothSocket;
import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.ClipData;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.IntentFilter;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Parcelable;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.KeyEvent;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.os.Handler;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.UUID;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        configureBluetooth();
        setupListView();
        setupSearchButton();
        setupListenButton();
    }

    private BluetoothAdapter bluetooth;
    private BluetoothSocket socket;
    private UUID uuid = UUID.fromString("a60f35f0-b93a-11de-8a39-08002009c666");
    private void configureBluetooth() {
        bluetooth = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();
    }

    private Handler handler = new Handler();
    private void switchUI() {
        final TextView messageText = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.messageview);
        final EditText textEntry = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.messagetext);
        messageText.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        list.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        textEntry.setEnabled(true);
        textEntry.setOnKeyListener(new View.OnKeyListener() {
            public boolean onKey(View view, int keyCode, KeyEvent keyEvent) {
                if ((keyEvent.getAction() == KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN) &&
                        (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_DPAD_CENTER)) {
                    sendMessage(socket, textEntry.getText().toString());
                    textEntry.setText("");
                    return true;
                }
                return false;
            }
        });

        BluetoothSocketListener bsl = new BluetoothSocketListener(socket,
                handler, messageText);
        Thread messageListener = new Thread(bsl);
        messageListener.start();

    }

    private void sendMessage(BluetoothSocket socket, String msg) {
        OutputStream outStream;
        try {
            outStream = socket.getOutputStream();
            byte[] stringAsBytes = (msg + " ").getBytes();
            stringAsBytes[stringAsBytes.length - 1] = 0;
            outStream.write(stringAsBytes);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.d("BLUETOOTH_COMMS", e.getMessage());
        }
    }

    private static int DISCOVERY_REQUEST = 1;

    private void setupListenButton() {
        Button listenButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.listen_button);
        listenButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Intent disc;
                disc = new Intent(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_REQUEST_DISCOVERABLE);
                startActivityForResult(disc, DISCOVERY_REQUEST);
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent
            data) {
        if (requestCode == DISCOVERY_REQUEST) {
            boolean isDiscoverable = resultCode > 0;
            if (isDiscoverable) {
                String name = "bluetoothserver";
                try {
                    final BluetoothServerSocket btserver =
                            bluetooth.listenUsingRfcommWithServiceRecord(name, uuid);
                    AsyncTask<Integer, Void, BluetoothSocket> acceptThread =
                            new AsyncTask<Integer, Void, BluetoothSocket>() {
                                @Override
                                protected BluetoothSocket doInBackground(Integer... params) {

                                    try {
                                        socket = btserver.accept(params[0] * 1000);
                                        return socket;
                                    } catch (IOException e) {
                                        Log.d("BLUETOOTH", e.getMessage());
                                    }

                                    return null;
                                }

                                @Override
                                protected void onPostExecute(BluetoothSocket result) {
                                    if (result != null)
                                        switchUI();
                                }
                            };
                    acceptThread.execute(resultCode);
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    Log.d("BLUETOOTH", e.getMessage());
                }
            }
        }
    }

    private ArrayList<BluetoothDevice> foundDevices;
    private ArrayAdapter<BluetoothDevice> aa;
    private ListView list;

    BroadcastReceiver discoveryResult = new BroadcastReceiver() {
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            BluetoothDevice remoteDevice;
            remoteDevice = intent.getParcelableExtra(BluetoothDevice.EXTRA_DEVICE);
            if (bluetooth.getBondedDevices().contains(remoteDevice)) {
                foundDevices.add(remoteDevice);
                aa.notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
        }
    };

    private void setupListView() {
        aa = new ArrayAdapter<BluetoothDevice>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, foundDevices);
        list = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list_discovered);
        list.setAdapter(aa);
        list.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View view,
                                    int index, long arg3) {
                AsyncTask<Integer, Void, Void> connectTask =
                        new AsyncTask<Integer, Void, Void>() {
                            @Override
                            protected Void doInBackground(Integer... params) {
                                try {
                                    BluetoothDevice device = foundDevices.get(params[0]);
                                    socket = device.createRfcommSocketToServiceRecord(uuid);
                                    socket.connect();
                                } catch (IOException e) {
                                    Log.d("BLUETOOTH_CLIENT", e.getMessage());
                                }
                                return null;
                            }

                            @Override
                            protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {

                                switchUI();
                            }
                        };
                connectTask.execute(index);
            }
        });
    }

    private void setupSearchButton() {
        Button searchButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.search_button);
        searchButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View view) {
                registerReceiver(discoveryResult, new IntentFilter(BluetoothDevice.ACTION_FOUND));
                if (!bluetooth.isDiscovering()) {
                    foundDevices.clear();
                    bluetooth.startDiscovery();
                }
            }
        });
    }

    private class MessagePoster implements Runnable {
        private TextView textView;
        private String message;
        public MessagePoster(TextView textView, String message) {
            this.textView = textView;
            this.message = message;
        }
        public void run() {
            textView.setText(message);
        }
    }

    private class BluetoothSocketListener implements Runnable {
        private BluetoothSocket socket;
        private TextView textView;
        private Handler handler;
        public BluetoothSocketListener(BluetoothSocket socket,
                                       Handler handler, TextView textView) {
            this.socket = socket;
            this.textView = textView;
            this.handler = handler;
        }

        public void run() {
            int bufferSize = 1024;
            byte[] buffer = new byte[bufferSize];
            try {
                InputStream instream = socket.getInputStream();
                int bytesRead = - 1;
                String message = "";
                while (true) {
                    message = "";
                    bytesRead = instream.read(buffer);
                    if (bytesRead != -1) {
                        while ((bytesRead==bufferSize)&&(buffer[bufferSize-1] != 0)) {
                            message = message + new String(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
                            bytesRead = instream.read(buffer);
                        }
                        message = message + new String(buffer, 0, bytesRead - 1);
                        handler.post(new MessagePoster(textView, message));
                        socket.getInputStream();
                    }
                }
            } catch (IOException e) {
                Log.d("BLUETOOTH_COMMS", e.getMessage());
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And this is the error that I'm getting

> 04-17 18:56:40.457 6684-6684/universityofhouston.dtntext
>   E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>                                                                              Process: universityofhouston.dtntext, PID: 6684
>                                                                              java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity
>   ComponentInfo{universityofhouston.dtntext/universityofhouston.dtntext.MainActivity}:
>   java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke interface method
>   'int java.util.List.size()' on a null object reference
>                                                                                  at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3155)
>                                                                                  at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3263)
>                                                                                  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1000(ActivityThread.java:197)
>                                                                                  at
>   android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1687)
>                                                                                  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
>                                                                                  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:145)
>                                                                                  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6897)
>                                                                                  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>                                                                                  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
>                                                                                  at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1404)
>                                                                                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1199)
>                                                                               Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke interface
>   method 'int java.util.List.size()' on a null object reference
>                                                                                  at android.widget.ArrayAdapter.getCount(ArrayAdapter.java:330)
>                                                                                  at android.widget.ListView.setAdapter(ListView.java:502)
>                                                                                  at
>   universityofhouston.dtntext.MainActivity.setupListView(MainActivity.java:160)
>                                                                                  at
>   universityofhouston.dtntext.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:39)
>                                                                                  at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6550)
>                                                                                  at
>   android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1120)
>                                                                                  at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3108)
>                                                                                  at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3263) 
>                                                                                  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1000(ActivityThread.java:197) 
>                                                                                  at
>   android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1687) 
>                                                                                  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
>                                                                                  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:145) 
>                                                                                  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6897) 
>                                                                                  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
>                                                                                  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372) 
>                                                                                  at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1404) 
>                                                                                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1199)

I think the error is here and is related to the Parcelable. I was reading a lot of posts related to this issue and i found a line of code that it might help me, but i don't know how to implement it in my code.

```
BroadcastReceiver discoveryResult = new BroadcastReceiver() {
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            BluetoothDevice remoteDevice;
            remoteDevice = intent.getParcelableExtra(BluetoothDevice.EXTRA_DEVICE);
            if (bluetooth.getBondedDevices().contains(remoteDevice)) {
                foundDevices.add(remoteDevice);
                aa.notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
        }
    };

    private void setupListView() {
        aa = new ArrayAdapter<BluetoothDevice>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, foundDevices);
```

Here is the code that i found.

```
  ArrayList<MyClass> mObjList;

  public void writeToParcel(Parcel out, int flags) {
      out.writeTypedList(mObjList);
  }

  protected MyClass(Parcel in) {
      mObjList = new ArrayList<>(); //non-null reference is required
      in.readTypedList(mObjList, MyClass.CREATOR);
  }
```

If any here knows how to implement this code or help me to find another way to fix this problem i would appreciate it. Sorry for the long post i just wanted to be as more as specific as i could so that would help you to find a better way to approach this issue.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is a Null Pointer Exception, and how do I fix it?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/218384/what-is-a-null-pointer-exception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Comment: I don't see where are you ever initializing `foundDevices`? That is likely leading to the `NullPointerException`.

Comment: Could you tell me how to initialize it? Thanks for your help BTW

Comment: `private ArrayList<BluetoothDevice> foundDevices = new ArrayList<>();`

Comment: Thanks for your help now the app is running. It doesn't do what i want yet, but at least I'm not getting the fatal error =D